# SVG Clipping with only generated Paths

Tags: c#, html, svg, clipping, dxf

I've programmed a sweet tool for converting DXF/DWG files into SVG - this works already. The target of this project is to create a SVG clipping from that AutoCAD file.

Here is an example of the generated svg-file:

```html
<svg width="231" height="586" viewBox="-1843.4575 -2473.4065 628 1588" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;fill:none">
      <g transform="scale(1,-1)">
        <!--Line-->
        <path d="M-1670.4575,936.6665 L-1670.4575,1276.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Arc-->
        <path d="M-1672.4575,934.6665 A2,2 0 0,1 -1670.4575,936.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Arc-->
        <path d="M-1670.4575,1276.6665 A2,2 0 0,1 -1672.4575,1278.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Line-->
        <path d="M-1672.4575,934.6665 L-1791.4575,934.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Line-->
        <path d="M-1672.4575,1278.6665 L-1791.4575,1278.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Arc-->
        <path d="M-1793.4575,936.6665 A2,2 0 0,1 -1791.4575,934.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Arc-->
        <path d="M-1791.4575,1278.6665 A2,2 0 0,1 -1793.4575,1276.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Line-->
        <path d="M-1793.4575,936.6665 L-1793.4575,1276.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Line-->
        <path d="M-1672.4575,1672.6665 L-1791.4575,1672.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Arc-->
        <path d="M-1670.4575,1670.6665 A2,2 0 0,1 -1672.4575,1672.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Arc-->
        <path d="M-1791.4575,1672.6665 A2,2 0 0,1 -1793.4575,1670.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Line-->
        <path d="M-1670.4575,1330.6665 L-1670.4575,1670.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Line-->
        <path d="M-1793.4575,1330.6665 L-1793.4575,1670.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Arc-->
        <path d="M-1672.4575,1328.6665 A2,2 0 0,1 -1670.4575,1330.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Arc-->
        <path d="M-1793.4575,1330.6665 A2,2 0 0,1 -1791.4575,1328.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Line-->
        <path d="M-1672.4575,1328.6665 L-1791.4575,1328.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Line-->
        <path d="M-1672.4575,2116.6665 L-1791.4575,2116.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Arc-->
        <path d="M-1672.4575,2116.6665 A2,2 0 0,1 -1670.4575,2118.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Arc-->
        <path d="M-1793.4575,2118.6665 A2,2 0 0,1 -1791.4575,2116.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Line-->
        <path d="M-1670.4575,2118.6665 L-1670.4575,2158.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Line-->
        <path d="M-1793.4575,2118.6665 L-1793.4575,2158.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Arc-->
        <path d="M-1556.0799,2297.1304 A141,141 0 0,1 -1670.4575,2158.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Arc-->
        <path d="M-1556.6636,2421.261 A264,264 0 0,1 -1793.4575,2158.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Arc-->
        <path d="M-1556.0799,2297.1304 A2,2 0 0,1 -1554.4575,2299.0945 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Arc-->
        <path d="M-1554.4575,2419.2716 A2,2 0 0,1 -1556.6636,2421.261 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Line-->
        <path d="M-1554.4575,2299.0945 L-1554.4575,2419.2716 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Line-->
        <path d="M-1672.4575,2066.6665 L-1791.4575,2066.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Arc-->
        <path d="M-1791.4575,2066.6665 A2,2 0 0,1 -1793.4575,2064.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Line-->
        <path d="M-1793.4575,1724.6665 L-1793.4575,2064.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Arc-->
        <path d="M-1670.4575,2064.6665 A2,2 0 0,1 -1672.4575,2066.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Arc-->
        <path d="M-1793.4575,1724.6665 A2,2 0 0,1 -1791.4575,1722.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Line-->
        <path d="M-1670.4575,1724.6665 L-1670.4575,2064.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Line-->
        <path d="M-1672.4575,1722.6665 L-1791.4575,1722.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Arc-->
        <path d="M-1672.4575,1722.6665 A2,2 0 0,1 -1670.4575,1724.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Line-->
        <path d="M-1504.4575,2299.0945 L-1504.4575,2419.2716 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Arc-->
        <path d="M-1504.4575,2299.0945 A2,2 0 0,1 -1502.8351,2297.1304 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Arc-->
        <path d="M-1388.4575,2158.6665 A141,141 0 0,1 -1502.8351,2297.1304 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Arc-->
        <path d="M-1502.2514,2421.261 A2,2 0 0,1 -1504.4575,2419.2716 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Line-->
        <path d="M-1388.4575,2118.6665 L-1388.4575,2158.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Arc-->
        <path d="M-1265.4575,2158.6665 A264,264 0 0,1 -1502.2514,2421.261 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Arc-->
        <path d="M-1388.4575,2118.6665 A2,2 0 0,1 -1386.4575,2116.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Line-->
        <path d="M-1265.4575,2118.6665 L-1265.4575,2158.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Line-->
        <path d="M-1386.4575,2116.6665 L-1267.4575,2116.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Arc-->
        <path d="M-1267.4575,2116.6665 A2,2 0 0,1 -1265.4575,2118.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Line-->
        <path d="M-1386.4575,1328.6665 L-1267.4575,1328.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Arc-->
        <path d="M-1388.4575,1330.6665 A2,2 0 0,1 -1386.4575,1328.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Arc-->
        <path d="M-1267.4575,1328.6665 A2,2 0 0,1 -1265.4575,1330.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Line-->
        <path d="M-1388.4575,1330.6665 L-1388.4575,1670.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Line-->
        <path d="M-1265.4575,1330.6665 L-1265.4575,1670.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Arc-->
        <path d="M-1386.4575,1672.6665 A2,2 0 0,1 -1388.4575,1670.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Arc-->
        <path d="M-1265.4575,1670.6665 A2,2 0 0,1 -1267.4575,1672.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Line-->
        <path d="M-1386.4575,1672.6665 L-1267.4575,1672.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Line-->
        <path d="M-1386.4575,2066.6665 L-1267.4575,2066.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Arc-->
        <path d="M-1386.4575,2066.6665 A2,2 0 0,1 -1388.4575,2064.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Arc-->
        <path d="M-1265.4575,2064.6665 A2,2 0 0,1 -1267.4575,2066.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Line-->
        <path d="M-1388.4575,1724.6665 L-1388.4575,2064.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Line-->
        <path d="M-1265.4575,1724.6665 L-1265.4575,2064.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Arc-->
        <path d="M-1388.4575,1724.6665 A2,2 0 0,1 -1386.4575,1722.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Arc-->
        <path d="M-1267.4575,1722.6665 A2,2 0 0,1 -1265.4575,1724.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Line-->
        <path d="M-1386.4575,1722.6665 L-1267.4575,1722.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Line-->
        <path d="M-1388.4575,936.6665 L-1388.4575,1276.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Arc-->
        <path d="M-1388.4575,936.6665 A2,2 0 0,1 -1386.4575,934.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Line-->
        <path d="M-1386.4575,934.6665 L-1267.4575,934.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Arc-->
        <path d="M-1386.4575,1278.6665 A2,2 0 0,1 -1388.4575,1276.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Arc-->
        <path d="M-1267.4575,934.6665 A2,2 0 0,1 -1265.4575,936.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Line-->
        <path d="M-1386.4575,1278.6665 L-1267.4575,1278.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Line-->
        <path d="M-1265.4575,936.6665 L-1265.4575,1276.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
        <!--Arc-->
        <path d="M-1265.4575,1276.6665 A2,2 0 0,1 -1267.4575,1278.6665 " style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.001;" />
      </g>
    </svg>
```

In every viewer it looks perfect. But not when i try to clip it.

I've reckon that it should't contain more than one MoveTo command, is that right?

Is it maybe because the coordinates are absolute?

I've tried to remove the M commands with no affect.
Also merged it into one Path with an "Z" close path at the end.

Would be niceif anyone has a solution.

Kind Regards

Comment: *In every viewer it looks perfect.* no, it doesn't, in Chrome it is empty ... becuase of stroke width

Comment: Yeah, i know but i don't need the style attributes! In my view it doesn't make a difference when clipping it, does it?

Comment: What do you mean by clip it? Do you want to use this as a clipping path?

Comment: Exactly!  Like this ->https://coderwall.com/p/blx8kw/svg-clippath-images

Comment: **1**. You have lots of repeated paths. **2**  Your paths are individual lines and arcs that do not inclose nothing. What you need is something like this: `<path d="M-1670.4575,936.6665 V1276.6665H-1791.4575V934.6665z"  />` **3**  If you fix errors 1 and 2 and you need to use this as a clipping path it won't work. You need to take everything out of the group. However since your group has a transform you will need to apply this transformation to every path. You can do it using CSS. Next you put everything in a `<clipPath>` element and use this to clip the svg image you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by myself!

What I've done is:

`1) Read all paths 
 2) Order them by "move to" and "end" points by matching coordinates. (if it is a curve, take care of the direction)
 3) Remove "move to" statements except the first one
 4) Merge all paths to one
 5) Append "Z" at the end to close the path.`

Additionally I've calculated all values into percent values.

The result is:

```
<path d="M0.77083,0.4699 L0.9962,0.4699 L0.9962,0.4699 A0.0037,0.0013 0 0,0 1,0.4685 L1,0.2398 A0.0037,0.0013 0 0,0 0.9962,0.2385 L0.7708,0.2385 A0.0037,0.0013 0 0,0 0.7670,0.2398 L0.7670,0.4685 A0.0037,0.0013 0 0,0 0.7708,0.4699 Z" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.001" style="fill:#ff0000;stroke-width:2.49098039" />
```